# iOS : change UINavigationItem titleView vertical position on popping a view controller

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I have different titleViews with different heights for different view controllers.

I am manually increasing the height of the the `UINavigationBar` that is used with a `UIViewController`

Because of the difference in heights, I must use the 
`- (void)setTitleVerticalPositionAdjustment:(CGFloat)adjustment forBarMetrics:(UIBarMetrics)barMetrics` so that the titleView is centered.

In my subclass of `UINavigationController` where I set its delegate to self :

```
-(void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated{

    CGFloat verticalAdjust;

    if(smallAdjust){
        verticalAdjust = 10;
    }else{
        verticalAdjust = 30;
    }

    [self.navigationBar setTitleVerticalPositionAdjustment:verticalAdjust forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

}
```

This works fine when I am pushing a new view controller onto the stack - positioning is as expected. However, when I pop a view controller and there is a change in the titleView (so that the the verticalPosition must be updated) the titleView does not get updated until the previous view controller's view has been shown. So essentially when I pop, the titleView stays at the position of the VC I am popping from and only when the view has been loaded its position adjusts itself.

How can I fix this ?

Comment: Have you tried putting setTitleVerticalPositionAdjustment: in a dispatch async block?

Comment: Just tried, nothing changes. The reason is that when the topmost vc is pushed onto the stack then its navigation's bar titleview is adjusted, and then when the vc is poppedm, the one `below` it uses the adjusted properties of the `navigationbar, but then after it loads - the values are adjusted - weird?

Comment: Yeah, it's weird that `willShowViewController:` is being called after the view controller is shown... (Maybe it's a bug?) But perhaps you can put that code in the view controller's own `viewWillAppear`.

Comment: Yeah tried as well..didnt work. Is it maybe something to do with autolayout ?